# Is there a better way to do innerHTML?

Tags: javascript

I want to know if there is a better way to be doing innerHTML than what I do here. The way I am doing it is causing problems because of the fact that I can't have triple nested quotes. along side that, it is really hard to look at and manage. Thanks!

```
function buttonClicked(buttonValue)
{
    switch (buttonValue)
    {   
        case 1:
            soundFolders.innerHTML = "<li onClick='buttonClicked(11);'>Thunder 1</li> <li onClick='buttonClicked(13);'>Light Rain 1</li> <li  onClick='buttonClicked(0);'>Back</li>";   
            break;

        case 11:
            if(!thunder1Control)
            {
                thunder1.play();
                var thunder1Control = document.createElement("li");
                soundList.appendChild(thunder1Control);
                thunder1Control.innerHTML = "<h3>Thunder 1</h3> <button class='stopSound' onClick='thunder1.pause(); thunder1.currentTime=0; thunder1Control.parentNode.removeChild(thunder1Control); '>X</button> <button  class='volDown' onClick='thunder1.volume -= 0.25;'>-</button> <button class='volUp' onClick='thunder1.volume += 0.25;'>+</button>";
                thunder1Control.setAttribute("class", "playingSound");
            }
```

P.S. Do you guys know why the `thunder1Control.parentNode.removeChild(thunder1Control)` is not working?

Comment: Your `.removeChild()` should work if `thunderControl` has a `.parentNode`. Is there a reason you're replacing all the content of the elements? Can't you just update specific nodes?

Comment: Looking into unobtrusive javaScript, it may help your overall design.

Comment: Move all those onclick handlers out of the HTML definition.

Comment: ...oh, it's in the inline handler. The only variables that you'll be able to access will be globals, or ones created in the attribute. You could use `this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);`. But I agree with the others. That's way too much JS to embed in HTML.

Comment: Looks like you should be using buttons instead of LIs, and using *style.display* `none` and `""` to hide and show relevant elements.

Comment: There are many "different" ways to dynamically show/create content.  What is "better" is primarily a matter of opinion which is not really how SO wants their questions because that's a matter of opinion. You could perhaps change your question to ask what other ways are there to manage the dynamic content shown in this code snippet?

Comment: As for your question about `thunder1Control.parentNode.removeChild(thunder1Control)`, where is that code?  The only reason it won't work is if `thunder1Control` is either not a valid DOM reference or not currently in the DOM.  Since you show `thunder1Control` as a local variable, I would wonder if you have a scope problem and that variable is no longer valid when you are trying to use it.

Comment: @jfriend00: It's in the middle of all that code in the `onClick` attribute. That makes `thunder1Control` variable out of reach.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.
@Mike Brant How do I go about moving them? Do you have a link to somewhere I can read about it?

Answer (score 2):

To your first question about another way to approach this type of code, "best" is a matter of opinion so I won't really try to address what is best.  But, I will give you some alternatives:

1. Avoid putting code into strings in your HTML.  There are all sorts of limitations with that and you generally want to separate code from presentation anyway.
2. Install event handlers in your code with `obj.addEventListener()` instead of putting event handlers and code in your HTML.
3. Use classes and IDs or DOM queries from a particular point in the hierarchy to retrieve specific objects in your page rather than trying to save references to them in global variables.  In plain javascript, `element.querySelectorAll()` is pretty powerful.
4. In many cases, it's much simpler to just hide and show blocks of HTML using `obj.style.display = "none"` and `obj.style.display = "block"` than it is to dynamically create and destroy HTML and this has the added advantage of the HTML is all specified in the page and doesn't have to be shoehorned into a javascript string.
5. For large blocks of dynamic HTML that wouldn't work well with hide/show for whatever reason, you can dynamically load snippets/templates of HTML from your server using ajax or you dynamically create the HTML using javascript.  My first preference is generally hide/show and then if that isn't practical for some reason, it depends upon how much the HTML I want to insert varies based on the state for whether I'd rather load a template or create it dynamically using javascript.  If you have large blocks of HTML you have to fit in your javascript, it is messy with quoting, etc... - no way around that if you go that route other than using one quoting scheme for the JS string delimiter and the other in your HTML.
6. In your particular case, it sure looks like the hide/show method would be simple.

To your second question, this line of code:

```
thunder1Control.parentNode.removeChild(thunder1Control)
```

does not work because the `thunder1Control` variable is long, long out of scope when your click handler is executed because it's a local variable in your `buttonClicked()` clicked function.

When you put code into a string as part of HTML, it is evaluated in the global scope only so any variables that it tries to reference, must themselves be global in scope.

I'd suggest that you NOT put code into strings in your HTML like that.  Use references to actual javascript functions.  In that particular case, I'd have to see your HTML to know how to best advise you.  If there is only ever one `thunder1Control`, then I'd suggest you just put an id value on it and retrieve it with `document.getElementBtId()` when you need it rather than trying to save a reference to it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially two other ways that I can see:

1. Use a framework that helps with this kind of things.  Others have
   mentioned jQuery.  A commenter is arguing that it might be overkill
   to include a framework for just this.  I would argue that if you're
   doing *any* javascript at all, you should be using a framework to
   make it less terrible. But continue onto suggestion 2 if you
   disagree!
2. You can create each of the elements via plain old javascript and append it to the elements that you need, instead of inserting it directly into innerHTML.  ex.

   var li = document.createElement("li");

   soundFolders.appendChild(li);

   etc...

But, honestly, use jQuery with some of the suggestions from others. It's pretty small, and it will heavily clean up all of your javascript.  Include it via Google and it will likely already be cached in the users browser.
https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Answer (score -2):

I think a better alternative is to use jQuery, and then instead of using `.html()` (equivalent of innerHTML in jQuery), you can create a template with your html and use `.load()` instead. Works nicer and it's cleaner. And you don't have to worry about triple nesting quotes as you said.

Edit: I'm not sure why I'm getting downvoted so much here... The poster doesn't want to worry about triple nesting quotes. A simple and, to me, elegant solution is to use `.load()` and to create a template, rather than a really long string of html...

Comment: A suggestion to use your favorite library is not an answer. And either way, how would using `.html()` instead of `.innerHTML` do anything for nested quotes? Using `.load()` is for making server requests. Don't see how that's relevant here.

Comment: I'm not suggesting using `.html()` at all if you actually read my post. I suggested using `.load()` because s/he wouldn't have to muck around with nested quotes, because s/he could load the html template instead of writing a long string like in his example. Thanks for downvoting a perfectly good answer.

Comment: You're right. I missed the word "of". Still it's not a very good answer. There's no indication jQuery is used, and `.load()` makes no sense here. -1

Comment: I actually mentioned jQuery in my post as well. And you can use `.load()` even if you're editing offline (except in Chrome). It makes perfect sense because instead of `"<li onClick='buttonClicked(11);'>Thunder 1</li>`... this can actually go in a file, which is cleaner...

Comment: You miss the point. If OP isn't already using jQuery, then it makes no sense to use it just for something as simple as this. Editing offline? I don't know what you're getting at. If this is on a public website, you're going to have to make a server request if using `.load()`.

Comment: Posted asked for a better way than what he was doing. I thought my solution was nice and a 'better' way, however you define that. Clearly I shouldn't have said anything, because I'm getting flamed...

Comment: You're not getting flamed. Your answer is simply not relevant to the question, and doesn't contain very good suggestions. As such, you're getting downvotes. That's how the site works.